# Word vba suddenly throws error '-2146959355 (800800005)': Server execution failed

Tags: vba, ms-word, windows-10

A moderator suggested my post to [answers.microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sudden-word-vba-error-2146959355-800800005-server/eccfc428-eb34-49d3-95d0-207ce77e1743) also post my problem here.

A previously working macro converting docx files to txt from a selected folder suddenly can't get past "With objWordApplication" when the above error appears. Under certain circumstances while awaiting to complete, and switching from Word to File Explorer and back (but unsuccessfully) another message is presented (Microsoft security event, blocks the macro, screenshot below), but this does not show if I stay in Word; several ~WRC####.tmp files are created each time this macro error occurs (these temp file sizes appear the same as Normal.dotm). The first time this errored out the Normal.dotm was corrupted and Word needed to recreate.

Suggestions for a fix are very much appreciated.
Word 365 Edu
Windows 10 Edu 22H2

Part of the script up to the error stop is shown below:

```
Sub TranslDocx2Txt()
'
Dim objWordApplication As New Word.Application
Dim objWordDocument As Word.Document
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCurrDir As String
Dim fldpath As String
Debug.Print CurDir
strCurrDir = CurDir 'keep track of current directory
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
Debug.Print CurDir
fldpath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)
ChDir fldpath 'change to the new directory
Debug.Print CurDir
' translates docx files to txt
strFolder = fldpath & "\"
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.docx", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
With objWordApplication
Set objWordDocument = .Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & strFile,
```

[image: VBA error]
[image: Windows security message]

A similar script with "With objWordApplication" errors out the same way. My antivirus log does not show interception, so this event appears to be a system thingy. Other complex scripts not employing this call run fine, and security setting in Word are to run all macros.

Comment: See this [MS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/security/internet-macros-blocked) ... you could unblock the file and/or move it into a trusted folder and run it from there. Though if you are running this code from within Word then you do not really need to create a new `Word.Application` as the `Application` object itself is already available to you

Comment: Thank you. OK, makes sense. Wonder why it began to error out. Appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Could be one of many things. Most likely I would say is that your AV got an update that makes it think your code is suspect and so it is virus checking every code instruction. But it can be just running the same code repeatedly ... I've seen it happen while I've been developing code and running it again and again and then it slows or is blocked ... then you move the file with the code and ... hey presto ... it runs again.

Comment: It's these little things sometimes that are frustrating, esp when edu versions of Windows and 365 like to keep updating, almost every 1-2 weeks!!! Not the first time I suspect an update caused a script to crash, but I have no hard info to say it did. Sometimes leaves machine unstable, having to roll back system, can't see a way to roll back 365.

Answer (score 0):

As Graham Mayor at answers.microsoft (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sudden-word-vba-error-2146959355-800800005-server/eccfc428-eb34-49d3-95d0-207ce77e1743) and @JohnM suggested, another instance of Word.Application is unnecessary when running within Word.

A complete solution was given by Graham Mayor.